# How do I change ActionColumn icons in Yii2 Gridview universally?

Tags: gridview, yii2, icons, font-awesome

With recent updates to Yii2, the glyphicons no longer display properly. I'd like to shift to font awesome icons universally.

How do I change the output of ActionColumn for all instances of GridView in one place?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of dependency injection container as [described here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container#practical-usage) and set it like:

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\ActionColumn', [/* new default configuration here */]);
```

or if you prefer to extend the class to modify it you can do what's described further down the aforementioned documentation and set the new definition for it:

```
$container->setDefinitions([
    'yii\grid\ActionColumn' => 'app\components\NewActionColumn',
]);
```

Comment: This is just what I've been looking for! But I'm not clear where these pieces of code should live. Is the idea that you would create a file/class **NewActionColumn.php** in **/components** and have it extend **yii\grid\ActionColumn**?

Where does the **$container->setDefinitions()** statement reside?

Comment: This should be placed somewhere where this code will be run every time so the usual place is the bootstrap file like [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/bootstrap.php). As for the `NewActionColumn` - yes, it's for extending grid's ActionColumn and you can place it wherever you want under the valid namespace.